# Call WebService on button click

Tags: java, web-services

i am a newbie to the WebService area, and seek some help.

I have been through the basics of deployment of WebServices on Tomcat container, however given a scenario that I want to call a WebService on button click, which when invoked will update some values in the database.
How can i achieve this , any examples would surely help

The WebService would be part of a different WAR, and needs to be called on button click from another Web application. So essentially , they would be part of 2 different WAR's

Comment: In swing or jsp or some other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't write soap call handling code in jsp. Write SOAP call handling code in Servlet or create another class to handle it and call it's method in Servlet. Then use Ajax to call this Servlet on button click.

References:

- [Jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- [SOAP Client in Java](http://harryjoy.wordpress.com/2011/10/20/soap-client-in-java/)

Comment: What are the JAR's that would be required in this case ??

Comment: For the code in above links, no jars are required. Just a .js file for jQuery.